# Update Manager reports a "404 - Failed to fetch" for a deb file

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, update-manager, connection

Update Manager is reporting this error:

```
Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-center/software-center_5.2.2_all.deb
404 Not Found
```

I checked and my Internet connection is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct package name is [software-center_5.2.2.2_all.deb](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-center/software-center_5.2.2.2_all.deb) (*three* point-twos, not two). The discrepancy is probably because you haven't updated recently and have the no-longer-available older `5.2.2` version in Update Manager's cache.

Press the <kbd>Check</kbd> button in Update Manager and then try Install again (thanks @EliahKagan!)

[image]

If that doesn't work, try opening the terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T` and then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`. Then close the terminal and try Update Manager again.

Comment: I ran the update and upgrade statement and received an error:  dpkg: error: dbkg status database is locked by another process.  Since I had closed Update manager I think I will need to restart and run it again.

Comment: @Dcm1405 If you've quit the Update Manager, and you're not currently running `apt-get` in the Terminal, and you still get that message, then you can fix `apt` and `dpkg` locking problems either by rebooting or by opening a Terminal window and running the commands in [step 5 of this procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure#Step_5).

Comment: @EliahKagan, I guess ubuntu was automatically checking for updates when I ran `apt-get`.  There are 147 items to be updated so I will let it run to see what happens.

Comment: @izx, after the `update && upgrade` I rebooted and... Sorry, Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error.  (follows a list of ~20 items).  Suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Did you try updating the repo?

apt-get update

There is also apt-get clean

I've had a similar error and then I did apt-get update and it was fixed. Hope this helps!

Comment: These commands have to be run as `root` with `sudo`. Also, `apt-get clean` won't help this (though it won't hurt)--it just removes cached `.deb` package files, but Ubuntu doesn't decide which version of a package to install based on what package installers are cached on the local machine.